# Naming of an organic compound containing nitrogen and fluoride

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I'm don't have a background in chemistry but I've been doing a project on computer aided molecular design and one of the resulting molecules was:

[image]

I'm having trouble naming this molecule let alone research if it is viable. I would appreciate any help in either naming or disqualifying it as infeasible.

Comment: Something along the lines of **difluoro(methyl)amine**. You also might find http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpca.5b05157 interesting.

Comment: Maybe not so simple considering that the PIN for $\ce{CH3-NH2}$ is methanamine but the PIN for $\ce{CH3-NH-F}$ surprisingly is N-methylhypofluorous amide and not N-fluoromethanamine.

Comment: @Loong The again, is OP even asking about PIN, and what about "feasibility"? The question isn't clear.

Comment: @Mithoron Usually, we cannot be sure if an OP even knows what a PIN is, so we cannot expect that a nomenclature question will explicitly ask for the PIN. Generally, we recommend answering such questions with the PIN (see [meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3121/103369)), but feel free to include other names in your answer.

Comment: @Loong thanks for the explanation. You were correct in guessing that I don't know what a PIN is. This was my first post and as I mentioned, I don't have a chemistry background. My question about feasibility was more of a general question. You could have looked at the molecule and said "that's not physically possible". That sort of thing. Thank you again.

Comment: The compound is definitely viable and has been subject to [a study](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Structure-and-Vibrational-Force-Field-of-CH3NF2.-An-Hagen-Hedberg/70448c4f4d131d96b6f6ca167ccfd9c3175c67a3). The compound was made by reacting dinitrogen tetrafluoride with methyl iodide. (m.p. -114.8 °C, b.p. -16°C and density of 1.099 at -20°C). @Loong The compound was previously named Methyldifluoroamine before changing the name by considering it an amide derivative as per new IUPAC rules.

Answer (score 4):

The IUPAC recommendations on this matter have been changed. Compounds such as $\ce{R{-}NH{-}Cl}$, $\ce{R{-}NH{-}NO}$, and $\ce{R{-}NH{-}NO2}$ are now named as derivatives of amides (see P-67.1.2.6).

The current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-00648)* reads as follows:

> **P-62.4** *N*-SUBSTITUTION OF AMINES AND IMINES BY HETEROATOMS
>
> Traditionally, substitution on the nitrogen atom of amines and imines was allowed for all characteristic groups cited as prefixes (see Table 5.1). This approach is maintained in these recommendations, unless a higher class is formed that must be named in accordance with the seniority of classes (see P-41).
> This new rule is applied to prefixes such as Cl and other halogen atoms, $\ce{{-}BrO}$ and other acyl similar groups, $\ce{{-}NO}$, $\ce{{-}NO2}$, $\ce{{-}OR}$, $\ce{{-}SO2{-}R}$, $\ce{{-}SO{-}R}$, and even $\ce{{-}OH}$ groups and
> chalcogen analogues.

Thus, the preferred name for the compound that is given in the question is ***N*-fluoro-*N*-methylhypofluorous amide** and not *N*,*N*-difluoromethanamine.

A similar example given in the Blue Book is $\ce{CH3{-}N{-}(NO2)2}$, which is named ***N*-methyl-*N*-nitronitramide** and not *N*,*N*-dinitromethanamine.

Comment: It could be that this is still not the correct answer, since there was a correction to the Blue Book concerning the _N_ locants in 2021.